# Given a set of distance constraints between points, how to find dimensionality of space?

Tags: general-topology

For example, we might have 3 points a, b, and c. If we apply these constraints: $x_{a,b}=5,x_{b,c}=3,x_{a,c}=3$, we know that these three points are impossible to fit on a line, but is possible to be placed on a 2D plane. But if we remove one of the three constraints, these three points then can reside on a 1D space. It's intuitive in low dimensions, but how can we extend this to higher dimensions?

Note: This question is different from existing questions such as [Given distances between points find dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3374084/given-distances-between-points-find-dimension), in that the constraints don't have to be all the pairwise distances. Instead only some of the distances are provided. Here's the background of the question if it helps you understand it: I'm given a weighted graph, and assuming that each node is a point in some euclidian space and the edge weight to be the distance between nodes, I'm interested in finding the minimal dimension that can satisfy the constraints posed by edge weights. Any types of answers are welcome, thank you!

Edit: Sorry, this description might not be clear enough. This graph that I'm given does not have to be fully connected, meaning that the distance between some nodes are not constrained.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! This is an interesting question. I agree that your question is different from the one you linked to, but not for the reason you stated. In the linked question, all distances are provided; there are $m$ points, with $k = \binom{m}{2}$ distances provided (representing a distance for each pair of points). The subtle difference is, you are attaching specific distances to specific pairs of points, whereas the distances in the linked question, the distances are not for any specific pair of points.

Answer (score 1):

You can work out the dimension *precisely* by examining the rank of a Grammian matrix. Let's say we have $n + 1$ points $x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n$, and the distances between them. Without loss of generality, assume $x_0 = 0$, as it will simplify the notation.

Now, compute the dot products between each $x_i$ and $x_j$ for $i \neq j$ between $1$ and $n$. You can compute it like so:
$$x_i \cdot x_j = \frac{1}{2}(\|x_i\|^2 + \|x_j\|^2 - \|x_i - x_j\|^2),$$
which is known as $\|x_i - x_j\|$ is the distance between $x_i$ and $x_j$, while $\|x_i\|$ and $\|x_j\|$ are the distances from $x_i$ and $x_j$ respectively to $x_0$.

Then, fill these into the Grammian matrix for $x_1, \ldots, x_n$:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\|x_1\|^2 & x_1 \cdot x_2 & x_1 \cdot x_3 & \cdots & x_1 \cdot x_n \\
x_2 \cdot x_1 & \|x_2\|^2 & x_2 \cdot x_3 & \cdots & x_2 \cdot x_n \\
x_3 \cdot x_1 & x_3 \cdot x_2 & \|x_3\|^2 & \cdots & x_3 \cdot x_n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_n \cdot x_1 & x_n \cdot x_2 & x_n \cdot x_3 & \cdots & \|x_n\|^2
\end{pmatrix}.$$
The rank of this matrix is the dimension of the span of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, which is the number of dimensions of the affine hull of the points $x_0, \ldots, x_n$. So, simply row-reduce this matrix to row-echelon form, count the pivots, and you'll have your dimension.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! I am still kind of confused though, the method you proposed still involves a matrix of all pair-wise distances, how do we deal unspecified distances between points? Based on your comment on my question, I think you do understand what I'm asking, so I guess I just need a bit more hints as to how this works. Thank you!

Comment: Oh...Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. I clarified the question a bit and hopefully it's clearer now. The graph given to me doesn't have to be fully connected and therefore some constraints are not given.

Comment: @ChrisLiu That's much harder. I can't think of anything off the top of my head, but I'll think about it. I wouldn't hold your breath though.